# comparison Mann-Whitney test between groups

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

In my dataset I have columns:

***group*** which is grouping var 
 ***var*** which is range variable

I need to compare only the groups 1-2 and  1-3.
how to do it using `wilcox.test`?
Here the data.

```
mydat=structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), var = c(23L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 
23L, 24L, 24L, 23L)), .Names = c("group", "var"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `split` your data.frame by `group` and then `lapply` the test to the group pairs you want.

```
lst <- split(mydat, mydat$group)
lapply(lst[-1], function(DF) wilcox.test(DF$var, lst[[1]]$var, exact = FALSE))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but maybe you can help me in this related post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495838/joining-the-result-of-two-statistical-tables-in-one-table-in-r

Answer (score 0):

You can try a visual solution as well.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)
ggplot(mydat, aes(factor(group), var)) + 
    geom_boxplot() + 
    geom_signif(comparisons = list(c(1,3), c(1,2)), test = "wilcox.test", 
                test.args = list(exact = FALSE),step_increase = 0.1)
```

[image]