# Error in match.arg(p.adjust.method) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Here my data

```
mydat=structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), group = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), var = c(23L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 
24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 
24L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 23L)), .Names = c("id", "group", "var"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

I want to join two tables. 
id is identificator.

```
library(tidyverse)
mdyat %>% 
  with(.,pairwise.wilcox.test(var,id, group, exact =F)) %>% 
  broom::tidy() %>% 
 complete(id,group) %>% 
  left_join(mydat %>% 
              group_by(id,group)) %>% 
              summarise_all(c("mean", "sd", "median")) 
            by=c("id,group")
```

and get the error

```
Error in match.arg(p.adjust.method) : 
  'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

How to do that this script performed for each indentificator separately 
I.E. Desired output

```
id      mean    sd      median  p.value
1   1   23,5    0.5773503   23,5    NA
1   2   23,5    0.5773503   23,5    1
1   3   23,5    0.5773503   23,5    1
2   1   23,5    0.5773503   23,5    NA
2   2   23,5    0.5773503   23,5    1
2   3   23,5    0.5773503   23,5    1
```

Comment: Your error occurs in the pairwise.wilcox.test method. Did you just try the with part?

Comment: @Roland, i delete it. I accidentally

Comment: @Linus , this question related with this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495838/joining-the-result-of-two-statistical-tables-in-one-table-in-r#51497804. How can i do correct?

Comment: @Linus, also i tried with this part and got same error

Comment: pairwise.wilcox.test takes x= as vector and the group. afterwards there ist the p.value correction. You handing over 3 variables not 2

Comment: @Linus i understand, but I need calculate U.test for id and group and than calculate descriptive statistics and join results in desired table. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part can be fixed using `group_by` and `do` as follows.

```
mydat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  do({
    with(., pairwise.wilcox.test(var, group, exact =F)) %>% broom::tidy()
  }) 

 ## # A tibble: 6 x 4
 ## # Groups:   id [2]
 ##      id group1 group2 p.value
 ##   <int> <fctr>  <chr>   <dbl>
 ## 1     1      2      1       1
 ## 2     1      3      1       1
 ## 3     1      3      2       1
 ## 4     2      2      1       1
 ## 5     2      3      1       1
 ## 6     2      3      2       1
```

In order to combine this with the summary statistics, you need to decide which group you want to join with (`group1` or `group2`). In the following I joined with `group1`, so the `mean`, `sd` and `median` refer to `group1` and the `p.value` refers to the difference between `group1` and `group2`.

```
mydat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  do({
    with(., pairwise.wilcox.test(var, group, exact =F)) %>% broom::tidy()
  }) %>% 
  mutate(group1 = as.numeric(as.character(group1)), 
         group2 = as.numeric(as.character(group2))) %>%
  complete(group1 = mydat$group) %>%
  left_join(mydat %>% group_by(id,group) %>% summarise_all(c("mean", "sd", "median")), 
            by=c('id', 'group1'='group'))
```

Comment: shadow, it is mistake df2=mydat. I edited post. please check it

Comment: how can i join second part?

Comment: i see your edit. but i need join part with descriptive statistics

Comment: I don't understand how you want to joint the two parts. The Wilcoxon test is a test between two groups. In your expected output, you seem to always compare to group 1, and therefore you get NA p-values. Is that what you would like to do?

Comment: i want for each group separately for id, calculate wilcox test, and then calculate descriptive statistics. In my desired output i show it. I don't know how to do it. Similar task was in this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495838/joining-the-result-of-two-statistical-tables-in-one-table-in-r#51497804, but solution of Jimbou works only by group, without separating by id.

Comment: i got it, how to do it, it is simple do it. Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

Your function arguments are wrong:

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(var,id, group, exact =F)
```

`?pairwise.wilcox.test` states the correct syntax as:

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(x, g, p.adjust.method = p.adjust.methods,
                      paired = FALSE, ...)
```

which means the third function argument should be `p.adjust.method`, not `group`.

Comment: I need calculate U.test for id and group and than calculate descriptive statistics and join results in desired table.

Comment: What do you mean `for id and group`? Separately for either as grouping variables, or for each `id` separately with `group` as grouping variable?

Comment: yes, for each id separately with group as grouping variable