# cor.test between groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

This problem is similary on this problem.
[Error in match.arg(p.adjust.method) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517062/error-in-match-argp-adjust-method-arg-must-be-null-or-a-character-vector)
where wilcox.test calculated  for each id, separately with group as grouping variable. 
This solution is very helped me

```
mydat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  do({
    with(., pairwise.wilcox.test(var, group, exact =F)) %>% broom::tidy()
  }) %>% 
  mutate(group1 = as.numeric(as.character(group1)), 
         group2 = as.numeric(as.character(group2))) %>%
  complete(group1 = mydat$group) %>%
  left_join(mydat %>% group_by(id,group) %>% summarise_all(c("mean", "sd", "median")), 
            by=c('id', 'group1'='group'))
```

How to do same things, but for cor.test (Spearman)?
I don't need summarise_all(c("mean", "sd", "median")), 
as output i need `cor coef` between groups. 
I.E 
var for group1 correlates with var for group2 
var for group1 correlates with var for group3 and so on.

output

```
id  group1  group2  cor coef
<int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   
1   1.00    NA      NA
1   2.00    1.00    0,1
1   3.00    1.00    0,1
1   3.00    2.00    0,1
2   1.00    NA      NA
2   2.00    1.00    0,1
2   3.00    1.00    0,1
2   3.00    2.00    0,1
```

Here the data

```
mydat=structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), group = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), var = c(23L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 
24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 
24L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 23L)), .Names = c("id", "group", "var"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function to create `pairwise.cor.test`s. You can replace `pairwise.wilcox.test` in your code and that should give you the desired output. I didn't check it for all possible things that could go wrong to give it a test before putting it in production:

```
pairwise.cor.test <- function (x, g, p.adjust.method = p.adjust.methods, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"), ...)
{
  method <- match.arg(method)
  p.adjust.method <- match.arg(p.adjust.method)
  DNAME <- paste(deparse(substitute(x)), "and", deparse(substitute(g)))
  g <- factor(g)
  compare.levels <- function(i, j) {
    xi <- x[as.integer(g) == i]
    xj <- x[as.integer(g) == j]
    cor.test(xi, xj, method=method, ...)$p.value
  }
  PVAL <- pairwise.table(compare.levels, levels(g), p.adjust.method)
  if (method=="pearson")
    METHOD <- "Pearson's product-moment correlation"
  if (method=="kendall")
    METHOD <- "Kendall's rank correlation tau"
  if (method=="spearman")
    METHOD <- "Spearman's rank correlation rho"

  ans <- list(method = METHOD, data.name = DNAME, p.value = PVAL,
              p.adjust.method = p.adjust.method)
  class(ans) <- "pairwise.htest"
  ans
}
```

I essentially just adapted the code from `pairwise.wilcox.test`. If you run this function on your data you get a lot of warnings because there is a lot of ties in your data (and no real variation) so I added `exact=FALSE` in the call to prevent exact computations.

```
mydat %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    do({
        with(., pairwise.cor.test(var, group, method="spearman", exact=FALSE)) %>% broom::tidy()
    }) %>% 
    mutate(group1 = as.numeric(as.character(group1)), 
           group2 = as.numeric(as.character(group2))) %>%
    tidyr::complete(group1 = mydat$group) %>%
    left_join(mydat %>% group_by(id,group) %>% summarise_all(c("mean", "sd", "median")), 
              by=c('id', 'group1'='group'))
```

This produces

```
# A tibble: 8 x 10
# Groups:   id [?]
     id group1 group2 p.value var_mean var2_mean var_sd var2_sd var_median var2_median
  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1      1     NA      NA     23.5    -0.990  0.577   0.937       23.5     -0.824 
2     1      2      1       0     23.5     0.551  0.577   0.799       23.5      0.523 
3     1      3      1       0     23.5    -0.548  0.577   0.693       23.5     -0.243 
4     1      3      2       0     23.5    -0.548  0.577   0.693       23.5     -0.243 
5     2      1     NA      NA     23.5    -0.532  0.577   1.83        23.5     -1.26  
6     2      2      1       0     23.5    -0.475  0.577   1.15        23.5     -0.367 
7     2      3      1       0     23.5     0.161  0.577   1.28        23.5      0.0778
8     2      3      2       0     23.5     0.161  0.577   1.28        23.5      0.0778
```

**Update:** 
To get just the output with the p values you can reduce the data wrangling:

```
mydat %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    do({
        with(., pairwise.cor.test(var, group, method="spearman", exact=FALSE)) %>% broom::tidy()
    })
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     id group1 group2 p.value
  <int> <fct>  <chr>    <dbl>
1     1 2      1            0
2     1 3      1            0
3     1 3      2            0
4     2 2      1            0
5     2 3      1            0
6     2 3      2            0
```

I'll add the function to the `MESS` package later tonight to save it for later.

Comment: best solution. But how can i delete  mean ,sd,median? In this task , it is not needed.

Comment: Just drop all your complicated `tidyverse` wrangling. See edit